# Problem reading element attributes with jQuery in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I swear the following code used to work, even in IE7 but now i get

Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

```
$('div').each(function() {
  if(! this.attr('id').startsWith('light') ) {  
    this.css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
    zIndexNumber -= 10;
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

SOLUTION

```
        $('div').each(function() {

        var divId = new String ( $(this).attr('id') );

        if(! divId.indexOf('light') == 0 ) {  
            $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
            zIndexNumber -= 10;
        }

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
$(this)
```

instead of

```
this
```

`$(this)` creates the jQuery object on which you can use all the jQuery functions. `this` is "only" the DOM element and this element has no e.g. properties `attr()` or `css()`.

**Update:**

Are you sure `.startsWith()` exists? Have you defined it yourself because JS has no such function afaik.

Try:

```
if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('light') == 0)
```

Comment: Yes, that was the first version of the script, but it was generating the same error.

Comment: lbolognini: what happens when you enter the following in the address bar? `javascript:alert(''.startsWith);`

Comment: On IE7 that gives me undefined

Comment: @lbolognini: Have you tried it the way I proposed? `startsWith` is not a JS function.

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but based on your code it looks like you don't need to use an if statement at all if you change your selector:

```
$('div[id^=light]').each(function() {

        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
        zIndexNumber -= 10;

});
```

`div[id^=light]` in your selector means "get all divs whose id begins with 'light'".

Similarly, `div[id$=light]` will select all divs whose id ends with 'light', and `div[id*=light]` will select all divs whose id contains 'light' anywhere in it.

This isn't even limited to id. You can use this on any attributes on any element. I know I found this very useful when I first discovered it.